# Почему валится ошибка при сохранении модели из консоли?

Tags: php, yii2

Использую advanced шаблон приложения и консольный контроллер. В экшене перетаскиваю данные из старой бд с изменением структуры. До этого все работало нормально, но сейчас возникает какая-то странная ошибка при вызове метода `save()` у модели. Причем `find()` работает нормально (я дебажил).

`Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Application::getSession()'`

Но я нигде там не использую этот метод getSession. Я вообще там сессии не использую. Никак не могу понять откуда берется эта ошибка? До этого как я сказал уже немало данных было перенесено и все нормально сохраняло.

Comment: а весь путь ошибок как выглядит?

Comment: @n.osennij с виндовой консольки не выходит скопировать так что вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/odKrZ.png (так и не смог понять как-тут изображения вставлять)

Comment: Ну вот. Тут указан весь путь возникновения ошибки Ищите среди этого то, что вы делали, спускаясь ниже и ниже

Comment: @n.osennij Ну я вижу только что после вызова save все валится. Но не догоняю зачем он вообще в модель юзера лезет. В моем коде она не используется.

Comment: не знаю. Попробуйте через gii сделать

Comment: @n.osennij я все вручную делаю. Еще ни разу gii не пользовался и не горю желанием. Когда вручную делаешь - лучше понимаешь что происходит. А когда за тебя код генерится - хрен поймешь что он там на генерил.

Comment: может и так. Но то, что он сгенерит можно ведь в итоге подправить.

Comment: @n.osennij да что конкретно вы предлагаете генерировать? То что у меня в консольном контроллере? Не выйдет. Там очень сложная логика с залезанием в другие БД на которые нет моделей.

Comment: Я насчет юзера нашел только то что есть FK user_id в Article. Но не представляю как это может вызывать такую ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опа, я нашел в чем было дело. Я вызывал метод `save()`, а он дергал валидацию. Но у меня в модели Article есть user_id (FK на юзера), а в rules висит такое правило `['user_id', 'default', 'value' => Yii::$app->user->id]`. По всей видимости у одной из статей не указан юзер был и валидатор пытался подтянуть текущего, что невозможно в консоли. В общем я запустил `save(false)` без валидации и все прошло.

Comment: Точнее говоря в консольном контроллере `Yii::$app->user` в принципе всегда будет пустой потому что сессии нет.